# Adding Text File into sqllite with java

Tags: java, database, file, sqlite, text

I been having trouble working with sqllite . I need to do a kinda file manager, it would make the person click on something choose the file they want to upload to the database, and store it there. I was reading you could use BLOB but gave up on it since I could not find a solid tutorial, what I was trying to do now was store the id ,author and book title in the database as well as the DIRECTORY of the file in the database so it can be called from the database itself when the data needs to be retrieved and displayed on the gui(Which i have not finished completely. I hope it makes sense here is my code, been playing around with it but no luck.

```
package groupproject;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Rafa579
 */


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SQLProject{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    // load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
      // create a database connection
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:books.db");
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.
      statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists books");
      statement.executeUpdate("create table books (id integer, author string, textinfo      string)");

      statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(1, 'Harry Potter','BIG SPACE HERE')");
      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from books");
      while(rs.next())
      {
        // read the result set
        System.out.println("author = " + rs.getString("author"));
        System.out.println("id = " + rs.getInt("id"));
      }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
      // if the error message is "out of memory", 
      // it probably means no database file is found
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
        if(connection != null)
          connection.close();
      }
      catch(SQLException e)
      {
        // connection close failed.
        System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
  public void addRowToCoffeeDescriptions(
    String coffeeName, String fileName)
    throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        Clob myClob = this.con.createClob();
        Writer clobWriter = myClob.setCharacterStream(1);
        String str = this.readFile(fileName, clobWriter);
        System.out.println("Wrote the following: " +
            clobWriter.toString());

        if (this.settings.dbms.equals("mysql")) {
            System.out.println(
                "MySQL, setting String in Clob " +
                "object with setString method");
            myClob.setString(1, str);
        }
        System.out.println("Length of Clob: " + myClob.length());

        String sql = "INSERT INTO COFFEE_DESCRIPTIONS " +
                     "VALUES(?,?)";

        pstmt = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, coffeeName);
        pstmt.setClob(2, myClob);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(sqlex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Unexpected exception: " + ex.toString());
    } finally {
        if (pstmt != null)pstmt.close();
    }
}
}
```

Am doing kinda like a book reader  using .txt file, Thanks alot if anybody  could help me out and explain what would be good and/or how to progress. Thanks :)

Comment: so what is going wrong? Any errors?

Comment: well am not sure how to extract the information from a location on c: or anywhere and put it on the database, i just put things together on here but not sure what it does. lol